# Why do coordinates depend on time in an eulerian point of view?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, flow

In all sources I read so far about fluid dynamics, we adopt an eulerian point of view, where we focus on a *fixed* position in space $(x, y, z)$ and we study the variation of the velocity vector at this position with respect of time.

Now when we compute the acceleration $a$ at that point (change of the velocity vector at that point), we say $a = \frac{dv(x,y,z,t)}{dt}$ where $v$ is the velocity, and we use the chain rule with the justification that x, y, z depend on t.

This gets me confused, as we said we are adopting an eulerian point of view where we look at a fixed point, why do its coordinates depend on time in this case?